# Return first index in multidimensional array using map

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have following scenario where I need loop through a data set and return multiple post. Each post has a title and few images attached to it. I am able to loop through all the data, but its returning the same title multiple times instead of just once.

Desired output:

My title
img 1
img 2

Current Output:

My title
image1
My title
image 2

JS:

```
const mappedFlickr = this.state.articles.map((flickr, i) => { 
        return ( 
          flickr.fields.featuredImage.map((st, i) => { 
             return ( 
                <div>
                <span>{flickr.fields.title}</span>
                <img src={st.fields.file.url +'?w=300&h=300'} />
                </div>
              )
          })
        )
     })

return (
      <section>
         { mappedFlickr }
      </section>
    )
```

Comment: Yes, `flickr.fields.title` will be the same title regardless what image you have in the loop. Why don't you move the `<span>` out of the `featuredImage.map`, right in the `<section>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move inner map inside `div`

```
const mappedFlickr = this.state.articles.map((flickr, i) => { 
        return ( 
           <div key={i}>
              <span>{flickr.fields.title}</span>
              {
               flickr.fields.featuredImage.map((st, j) => 
                 (<img key={j} src={st.fields.file.url +'?w=300&h=300'} />)
               )
              }

            </div>
        )
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `<span>{flickr.fields.title}</span>` outside of the inner loop